# Is there a way to select a certain number of row for a certain column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
+----+---------+----------+-------+
| id | user_id | other_id | score |
+----+---------+----------+-------+
| 1  | 1       | 1        | 80    |
| 2  | 1       | 2        | 40    |
| 3  | 1       | 3        | 60    |
| 4  | 2       | 2        | 70    |
| 5  | 2       | 4        | 50    |
| 6  | 2       | 3        | 40    |
| 7  | 2       | 5        | 90    |
+----+---------+----------+-------+
```

I want to sort each `user_id` by `score` and only return maximum `n` (e.g., 2) rows for each `user_id`. So I want to get the result as:

```
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 80 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 60 |
| 7 | 2 | 5 | 90 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 70 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: The last row in the required result is `4 | 2 | 2 | 70`, right?

Comment: I suggest use limit if you are using MYSQL is not portable but play well with mysql http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: Which row to select if there are two rows with score 80 for user 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily done by using a subselect,comparing the count with same table

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 t
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    Table1  t1
            WHERE t1.user_id = t.user_id AND 
                  t1.score >= t.score
        ) <= 2
ORDER BY t.user_id ASC,t.score DESC
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98670e/4)

Comment: I would remove the equals signs (ie `t1.score > t.score` and `< 2` to simplify (slightly)

Comment: superb .. i was puzzled about doing this in mysql which has no row_number() and partition by.. +1

Comment: @Bohemian yes you are right my bad in previous comment i have not properly used what you have stated thanks [*fiddle reference*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98670e/11)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  id, user_id, other_id, score
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM yourtable a 
           WHERE a.user_id = yourtable.user_id 
             AND a.other_id= yourtable.other_id);
```

Comment: This will only work for n=1, i.e. if you want exactly one row per user.

Comment: It's true :) Thanks @Frank Schmitt

Answer (score 0):

```
select id , user_id , other_id , score from (select id , user_id , other_id , score,if(@tempvar=user_id,@i:=@i+1,@i:=1) as occurrence, @tempvar:=user_id  from (select * from (select  id , user_id , other_id , score from tablename order by score desc)t order by user_id )tempA,(select @tempvar='',@i=0)tempB)tempc where occurrence<3 group by user_id,occurrence
```

I tried with your data and get expected result. Just replace tablename  to your table name and try above query